# Python I/O Error while making Value exception

Tags: python, exception, io

I am trying to make a basic cryptographical program. While trying to make exception for encoded character being over chr(256), i have various problems which i cannot get over:

```
        try:
            while 1:
                a=input_file.read(1)
                if tick>1 and not a: break
                if i==32: i=0
                z=(ord(a)+harden(ord(key[i]),x))
                text+=chr(z)
                i+=1
                if tick%400==0: 
                    print "\rProcessing file",'.'*processing,"                        ",
                    processing+=1
                tick+=1
        except ValueError:
            x+=1
            place+="-"+str(tick)
            tick-=1
            input_file.seek(tick)
```

All the rest is fine, every variable used is initialized. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is `input_file`? Which `ValueError` are you catching?

Comment: Try out Python 3 or you can use `unichr()`.

Comment: Input_file=open(input_filename, 'rb')

Comment: And ValueError: out of range(256) or sth like this. After this error i want it to change x (which is important part of harden() function, defined already, so that it z is no longer bigger than 256